# Creating supernode

Tags: rosnode

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to create a node which handles other nodes.
Like it looks into the clients and their requests, and looks for the servers which provide the required service, starts those servers and provide the corresponding service to the client. How do i go about it?
Thanks in advance...

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10366/creating-supernode/) by [Kamal](https://answers.ros.org/users/740/kamal/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2011-06-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[rosh](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosh) offers introspection capabilities into the ROS API and may offer a good set of tools to start with.

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2011-06-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0